# Behavior of set -e in function calls

Tags: bash, shell-script, exit, error-handling

I have an unusual problem with -e flag in a following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
foo() { return 1; }
bar() { foo; bar; }
bar || exit 1
```

Namely the script does not terminate, even though the foo function returns 1.
However after removing '|| exit 1' part this script works as expected- it fails just after the first foo execution.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
foo() { return 1; }
bar() { foo; bar; }
bar
```

EDIT:
bash versions tested:
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Yes, the `||` cancels `set -e` for the whole evaluation of the function.